# Magento : How to get model

Tags: php, magento

I have this URL with me 
admin/catalog_category/edit/key/0ff0928cf61018af19089207bbaedf15/id/63/?isAjax=true

from this how can i get which model is working and which template is working..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

admin/catalog_category/edit/

Here,

```
Module = catalog = app/code/core/Mage/Catalog
Controller = category = controllers/CategoryController.php
Action = edit = editAction()
```

So, to get the template file and PHP file for this action, look in the module's XML file i.e. `app/design/frontend/default/THEME/layout/catalog.xml`

You will find handle name `catalog_category_edit` for the action method `editAction()`.
Inside this handle, you will see all the blocks and associated template paths with it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ravi that's because there are myriad amount of articles on Magento Architecture on net. and downvote means `This question does not show any research effort;`

Comment: Hi kalpesh i am facing another problem with magento admin that i cant see my category form under catalog > manage categories i can see the form on first load then it disappears in firebug no html is coming also cant see any ajax action in firebug console.. but when i load the ajax url in another tab response is there.. not getting what is going on..

Comment: it would be better to post a new question with screeshots for your problem to better understand what's going wrong.

Comment: here is the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908506/magento-admin-category-form-is-not-diaplaying